# How do I animate a character without creating 100's of keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a basic rig with a character.  The only things that are moving are the torso, arms, and the knees.

For my beginning pose, I insert every available keyframe as the base pose.  On phase 2, I update the torso, arms, knees, etc.  Then I copy all the keyframes from pose 1, to set it back to normal.

Do you see the issue here? In pose 1 and pose 3, there are 100's of keyframes that need to be cleaned up because they're not being updated?  The only way I can think of cleaning these up is the go into the Action Editor and deselect all the bones I'm not updating and delete the rest.

Comment: I'd suggest you watch a simple animation tutorial! In Pose mode, at frame 1 select the whole armature with 'A' and hit 'I' > Location, Rotation and Scale. Move the Timeline marker to your 'phase 2' frame, pose your model, then hit 'I' > Loc, Rot & Scale again. (You only need to do this with the bones you've moved but selecting All and insert them all again is probably easier in your case.) Then you can go back to frame 1, box-select your keyframes, hit Shift-D to Duplicate then drag them to your final frame. There's no need to use the action editor at all.

Comment: Wouldn't this have keyframes for every bone in all 3 phases?  You're duping everything.  The way I had it before, at least phase 2 only had the bones I wanted to move.

Comment: Yes it would, but that's the easiest way in your case and doesn't really matter. You could also set keyframes for everything on the first frame. Turn on Auto Keying (Top of the Timeline to the left of the movement icons), pose your model, then move on one frame. Then do the duplication as before. Don't forget to turn off Auto Keying though as any movement will be recorded which might not be what you want and is why I rarely use it.

Comment: Actually you only need to use Location and Rotation unless you intend to scale any bones, and if you think about it moving the torso will also move all the bones above it in the model at the same time, so keyframing the whole model is necessary or it will try to pull itself apart!

Comment: No offense, but that is the way I was trying to avoid because of all the keyframes I don't need.  I guess there's no short way to do it without deleting them manually on the frame.

Comment: __You__ may not think you need the keyframes, but the armature certainly will!